# delete role from server

Tags: node.js, roles, discord.js

So, call me dumb... but I can't get something figured out as to deleting a role from a server permanently. I have role being made for each pair of users that are playing a game in a channel. The role is purely to allow only the 2 players to comment in the channel. I am trying to remove the role once the game is done. The role can be either one of two formats, depending on who was specified as player A and which was player B in a previous separate command.

The below code is giving errors of:

> "(node:19308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of null"

The `console.log(bRole)` line is displaying the two users with their usernames not nicknames, so that might be why the find is giving null? The command originally takes mentions. I can't remove all roles or a specific role ID, because the role is generated in a different command with the names of the two players as the role title.

Here is the code:

```
// !endbrawl winner [username] loser [username]

      let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
      let winner = messageArray[2]
      let winnerUser = message.mentions.users.first();
      let loser = messageArray[4]
      let loserUser = message.mentions.users.last();

    bRole = `${winner.displayName} vs ${loser.displayName}` || `${loser.displayName} vs ${winner.displayName}`
    console.log(bRole)
    guild.roles.find("name", bRole).delete();
```

I'm just unsure how I'd go about letting the bot find the role so it can be removed. I might just be missing something super simple and easy. Thanks so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you show me what you have defined `guild` as?

Comment: I've been messing with it a lot today but I think I had "let guild = message.guild" at the time I posted the code above. The command is posted in a channel on the server that the role will be used on.

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot read property 'delete' of null"` means `guild.roles.find("name", bRole)` returned `null`, most likely because no role was found! You can try using the normal `.find()`:

```
guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'RoleName').delete();
```

As the roles change name you wanna do

```
guild.roles.find(role => role.name == `${winner.displayName} vs ${loser.displayName}` || role.name ==`${loser.displayName} vs ${winner.displayName}`).delete();
```

Comment: Right. The issue I'm having is that the role name is constantly changing. The role is made in the form of `${player A} vs ${player B}` through a command used previously.  I have it set up that way so the role only allows those 2 players from entering messages in the channel where their card game is taking place. I know how to remove a role that doesn't change title (or is reuseable), but one that changes according to the users in it is making this tougher for me. Player A isn't always the winner and vice versa.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, it still gives an error of "(node:10900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of null" I do still have guild defined as message.guild. Although, now that I am thinking about it. The response that is given right before the role would be removed is done via private message. Step 1: command is used in public server. step 2: bot reaches out to both players via private message, winner first, then loser only if the winner accepts results. Step 3: the bot should remove the role and moves the channel to another category.